# How to pass controller function parameters in codeigniter from forms?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a search city in my website, my search bar is a  option where they can select which city they want to view. but when i search a city in my website, it directs to this url:
foobar.com/s/

now i want the url to become like this: foobar.com/s/california

my select options have this format:

```
<select name='city'>
<option value='california'>California</option>
</select>
```

how can i make the value of the option be seen in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first redirect to foobar.com/s/california once user has selected the option from the Dropdown and then do routing to send your URL to respective controller

something like

```
  $route['s/(:any)'] = "s/your_method_name/$1";
```

Comment: is there other solution for this? redirecting seems slow since i need to direct user 2 times.

Comment: Redirecting is a only solution for changing in a URL, as we can not change the URL without redirecting. Or you have another solution to add # tag foobar.com/s/#california but in this way php script will not be able to get the city name.